# Open sublime text editor with predefined lines according to extension

Tags: command-line, ide, sublime-text

Ok so I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and use sublime text editor 2(currently but I'll be soon updating to 3) for programming in various languages.What I want is that sublime editor should open with specific lines when I create a new file with according to the extension of file like in ideone.For example: from terminal I do:

```
subl main.cpp
```

than sublime should open with:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Is there any plugin for this or if there isn't how do I make one of my own for this task?